# How is this word "совершившимся" in the following sentence derived?

Tags: глаголы, морфология

How is the word "совершившимся" derived? The sentence is:

> Меня поставили перед совершившимся фактом

I take it the root verb is совершить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's make the morphological analysis of the word:

*со-верш-и-вш-им-ся:*

- *со-* is a prefix
- *-верш-* is the root.

The two above define the semantics of the word, meaning "to complete". This is Russian form of the prefix, though, as @shabunc noted, CS form *с-* (*свершившимся*) is more widely used in this context.

- *-и-* is a suffix defining perfective aspect
- *-вш-* is a suffix defining active participle
- *-им-* is a flective postfix (*окончание*) defining single number and instrumental case
- *-ся* is a particle (merged with the word) defining reflexivity.

Hence, we have a past perfective reflexive active participle in sg. inst. (*действительное возвратное причастие совершенного вида прошедшего времени в творительном падеже единственного числа*)

Answer (score 5):

Actually the phrase is slightly outdated, the correct modern form is

> меня поставили перед **свершившимся** фактом.

from `свершиться` - to happen (about something that have been expected to happen).

Though совершившимся is technically possible, it is used nowadays very rarely.